# Receiving streaming data in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, streaming, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to test a Hadoop product, HStreaming, which allow Hadoop to process continuous stream of data. I access my twitter streams and my mapreduce program is not receiving any stream data from the twitter. But the same twitter url works from browser or wget or curl utilities. Just want to know - is there any configuration required to make MapReduce program access http (from firewall)?